# If I want to limit access in SSL/DTLS to a certain group of servers, what is wrong with just comparing Base64/pem files?

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

Reading up on SSL certificates. There is plenty of material on verifying certificates, CA roots, etc. However, if I want to be certain that only a given
group of servers can be accessed, is there anything wrong with just keeping a cache of the Base64/pem format certs in a file and comparing them?

I have seen answers on the web that the cert will change according to when it was accessed, so I got the pem on an example server, www.yahoo.com, then stored it, accessed the same server and got another pem later, and they matched. I suspect that the cert will be as good as a fingerprint until expiration or the server changes to a new cert.

My idea is to show the decoded cert to the user, then store the base64 verion in a file/cache to form a list of "very trusted servers", or alternately let the user simply form his/her own list of such servers.

The other answer I have seen is to store and compare the decoded version, but this does not seem to me to be as secure as directly comparing the encoded cert.

Thanks for opinions.

Comment: Seems a bit like what they are doing at https://www.certificate-transparency.org/. My (probably incomplete) understanding is that certs, although they are readable by anyone (clearly since any cert can be decoded), are RSA signed, and thus if left in their original/PEM form they are hack resistant.

Comment: Would also value opinions, if you are so inclined, about using the md5sum or similar hash function instead of storing the complete certificate.

Comment: The main question for me is: the peers execute a TLS/DTLS handshake based on that certificate before, so the crypto-stuff to ensure, that the peer has the corresponding private, is executed successful. Then the main drawback of your solution would be, that when the server-cersts are exchanged/refreshed, you would need to update your store. Validating the cert chain may relay on longer valid certificates and would therefore require less frequent updates.

Comment: Sure, absolutely. Establishing a whitelist for, say, general html servers on the web makes no sense for that reason. I should have explained, I am interested in TLS and DTLS communication lines based on custom servers such as my company has. We have a few servers that provide data to a network of satellite boxes, so I am thinking of a whitelist cache for both the clients and the servers, which would then hopefully make them fairly hack-proof. There's lots of similar applications where both the server and the client are under control of one organization.

Answer (score 0):

If the certificates are validated during the handshake according your requirements, then you may use such a whitelist.
Using "trust-management" is in my opinion not more complex than such a whitelist. Especially, of all peers are controlled by the same organisation. You can create your own CA (even a offlineCA, may be you setup a organisation specific process to ensure, that the CA's private key is used compliant), and as good as you protect that CA's private key, you may trust that CA. So simply use that CA certificate as "only" trust to your TLS/DTLS setups on client and server, and sign all client and server certificates with that CA.

Comment: So lets say I make a cert for my servers, and one for my clients. I'm going to get an SSL connect because its valid, then I need to check what field in the certificate? Subject key? The scenario I wonder about is: our box goes to the field, and we rely on the customer to hook it up to their WIFI, then it is going to connect via ssl to one of our servers. So lets say that server address gets spoofed, we connect to a fake server, which gives a fake but self signed cert. We don't have a CA, cause we self signed as well. Obviously we need to check cert contents.

Comment: If you use "self-signed" certs, it will be the public key you trust. The other peer proofs, that the corresponding private key is known in the handshake, e.g. using a client certificate, the certificate verify message is signed with the corresponding private key. If you trust the public key, that is considered as secure, as you can keep the private key secure (private). You may either use the complete certificate (which contains that prooven public key), that public key, or the fingerprint (with a hypothetical rest risk).

Comment: And just to mention it again, and even if you seems to prefer "self-signed/whitelist" approach: a CA may also be self-signed. And the private key of such a CA may kept offline, because it's only used to sign the certificates of the clients and server. And outsite this signing, only the public information is required.

Comment: Thanks for the good comments, I am hitting the books until I have this down better.